# Views filtering by taxonomy term = url(the view is placed)

Tags: views

So, im having a Products site right now, with submenu items of every category the Product belongs. I started with making a view for the first submenu category, and its filtering the results by taxonomy term.

I got 6 more submenu items and i want to reuse my view and not make 6 more with diferent taxonomy terms. I would like to make one universal view that filters by the url alias where the views block is placed.

So if im right, the view block placed on the site with the  "abc" url alias should show all products with the "abc" taxonomy value.

How do i set the view filtering for my needs?

I hope i express my idea clear.

Thanks in advance for help.

P.S. All the Submenu items are multilingual if that does matters. The url is not translated.